# Java: send POST HTTP request to upload a file to MediaFire REST API

Tags: java, http, rest, post, file-upload

I need to send a **HTTP POST request** to the **MediaFire REST API** from a **Java web app** running in **Google App Engine**, in order to upload a file.

Please see upload function documentation [**here**](http://developers.mediafire.com/index.php/REST_API#upload) (few lines).

Looking at the documentation and some research, I've written the following Java code to make the correspondent request:

```
byte[] bytesData = //byte array with file data

URL url = new URL("http://www.mediafire.com/api/upload/upload.php?" +
                    "session_token=" + sessionToken);

//Configure connection
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setReadTimeout(60000);

//Set headers
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
conn.setRequestProperty("x-filename", fileName);
conn.setRequestProperty("x-filesize", fileSize);
conn.setRequestProperty("x-filehash", sha256);

//Write binary data
System.out.println("\nWriting data...");
OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
out.write(bytesData);
out.flush();

//Check connection
//if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
//  throw new RuntimeException("FAILED!!! HTTP error code: " + 
//                             conn.getResponseCode() + " --- " + 
//                             conn.getResponseMessage());
//}

//Get response
System.out.println("\nGetting response...");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

//Print response
System.out.println("\nOutput from Server .... \n");
String output;
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(output);
}
```

But I'm not getting any result, just:

```
Writing data...
Getting response...
Output from Server:
```

If I *un-comment* the lines under `//Check connection` I get an `Exception`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: FAILED!!! HTTP error code: 503 --- OK
```

If I change the `Content-Type` header for `multipart/form-data` I get a different `Exception`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: FAILED!!! HTTP error code: 400 --- OK
```

I don't know too much about HTTP connections and so on and I have no idea about what's happening...

Any ideas about what may be going on?

---

*Note*: I'm using other (GET) methods of the API from the same app and they are working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP error Code: 400 is the status code for bad request, this probably means that the server does not except multipart/form-data, the 503 code means server overloaded, so this service may be hosted on a different server/thread on the server to the other GET methods, which may be receiving more traffic.